# Difference between `where` keyword inside or outside the curly braces

Tags: julia, where-clause

What is the difference between

```
function foo(a::Adjoint{Float64, Matrix{T}} where T)
    return 0
end
```

and

```
function foo(a::Adjoint{Float64, Matrix{T} where T})
    return 1
end
```

(Note the location of the curly braces.)

```
julia> methods(foo)
# 2 methods for generic function "foo":
[1] foo(a::Adjoint{Float64,Array{T,2}} where T) in Main at REPL[247]:2
[2] foo(a::Adjoint{Float64,Array{T,2} where T}) in Main at REPL[248]:2
```

It seems in both cases the function would accept an adjoint of Matrix of type `T`? I can't figure out what the difference between the two functions is.

Comment: Well, one of them returns `0` and the other returns `1` =P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first is a unionall type, the second is a concrete type:

```
julia> isconcretetype(Adjoint{Float64, Matrix{T} where T})
true

julia> isconcretetype(Adjoint{Float64, Matrix{T}} where T)
false

julia> (Adjoint{Float64, Matrix{T}} where T) isa Core.UnionAll
true
```

The first one is the infinite set of adjoints wrapping a `Matrix` of some type. In other words, we could imagine representing the infinite set in pseudocode with something like:

`Set([Adjoint{Float64, T} for T in all_possible_types])`

Whereas the second is an adjoint wrapping a `Matrix` of some type, or in other words:

`Adjoint{Float64, Matrix_of_any_type}`.

You almost always want the former, not the latter. There is little reason to construct an adjoint which can contain any `Matrix`, usually you just want an adjoint with one type.

The difference is clearer with `Vector`:

- `Vector{Vector{T}} where T` is a unionall representing all vector of same-type vectors.
- `Vector{Vector{T} where T}` is a vector containing the specific element type `Vector{T} where T`.

Comment: Thanks! For anyone reading this, this was helpful:
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#UnionAll-Types-1

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example that illustrates the difference, for the simpler case of `Vector{Vector{T} where T}` vs `Vector{Vector{T}} where T`.

First make some type aliases:

```
julia> const InsideWhere = Vector{Vector{T} where T}
Array{Array{T,1} where T,1}

julia> const OutsideWhere = Vector{Vector{T}} where T
Array{Array{T,1},1} where T
```

The default array constructor promotes elements to a common type if possible:

```
julia> x = [[1, 2], [1.2, 3.4]]
2-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
 [1.0, 2.0]
 [1.2, 3.4]

julia> x isa InsideWhere
false

julia> x isa OutsideWhere
true
```

But by using a [typed array literal](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Typed-array-literals-1) we can avoid the automatic promotion:

```
julia> y = ( Vector{T} where T )[[1, 2], [1.2, 3.4]]
2-element Array{Array{T,1} where T,1}:
 [1, 2]
 [1.2, 3.4]

julia> y isa InsideWhere
true

julia> y isa OutsideWhere
false
```